# in reactjs want to update parent state based on child state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**In reactjs I want to update parent state based on child state.**
**My parent component in Login.**
**I want child state in `Login` component role function**

```
//this function to show link //
function GetLink(props) {
    const { role } = props
    let admin = <Link to='/Admin'>Admin</Link>
    let f = <Link to='/Finance'>Finance</Link>
    let s = <Link to='/Sales'>Sales</Link>

    switch (role) {
        default:
        case "admin": return (
            <>
                {admin}
                {f}
                {s}
            </>
        )
        case "finance": return (
            <>
                {f}
                {s}
            </>
        )
        case "sales": return (
            <>
                {s}
            </>
        )
    }
}

//this is the parent component //
class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            role: ""
        }
    }

    //want this state to be update when child state is updated
    role = () => {
        this.setState({ role:  });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                { this.state.role === "admin" }
                <GetLink role={localStorage.getItem("role")} />
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

**now this is my child component where the state is updating in `componentDidMount`**

```
//this is child component //
//the state is updating in this component //
class Sales extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {role: "" }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (localStorage.getItem("role") === null) {
            this.props.setState({ role: localStorage.setItem('role', 'sales') })
        }
    }

    logout() {
        localStorage.removeItem('role');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <h1>Sales</h1>
                <button onClick={this.logout}>logout</button>
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default Sales;
```

**can anyone help me out with this problem?**

Comment: you can pass child state as a props and access and update in parent state.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the best way that you send a function as props.

```
<GetLink role={this.role} />
```

Comment: Or Please use Redux or Context.

Comment: this is already working fine but im asking for getting role from child to parent